# Why they are different if I run the command in linux directly and run it by importing os module in python?

Tags: python, linux, awk

I am doing two "similar" things:

(1) in python

`import os`

`os.system('cat ...input | awk -f ...awk' -v seed=$RANDOM)`

(2) in linux terminal

`cat ...input | awk -f ...awk' -v seed=$RANDOM`

Actually, my awk file will return a randomized input file, but if I run way(1) many times, the result always be same(only one result). But If I run way(2), then every time I can get a randomized file. What's wrong with it?

If I want to run this command in python, how should I do then?

Thank you so much for you answer.

**EDIT**:
Adding the actual code:

(1) in python

```
 import os 
 os.system("cat data/MD-00001-00000100.input | awk -f utils/add_random_real_weights.awk -v seed=$RANDOM")
```

(2) in linux:

```
cat data/MD-00001-00000100.input | awk -f utils/add_random_real_weights.awk -v seed=$RANDOM
```

Comment: Why don't you show us your actual, runnable code? The snippets in your question and not even syntactically valid.

Comment: ohh, sorry, thx for suggestion.
(1) in python
import os
os.system("cat data/MD-00001-00000100.input | awk -f utils/add_random_real_weights.awk -v seed=$RANDOM")
(2) in linux:
cat data/MD-00001-00000100.input | awk -f utils/add_random_real_weights.awk -v seed=$RANDOM

Comment: @Draco: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46021838/edit) your question and add the _formatted_ infromation there

Comment: Try replacing `os.system()` with `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` [17.1.4.3. Replacing os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)